# Duplicate jar entry android

Tags: android

I introduced the ros-android jar package in the android project, and ros-android depends on ros-java jar. Then I modified and directly modified a java file in the ros-java jar package, created a file with the same name, and modified the code inside. Finally run the project, this error is reported when I set `minifyEnabled = true`. Now I expect to load only the java files I copied when packaging, I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

This doesnt answer your question directly, but do you even need a .jar? The documentation for ROS states how to add it as a gradle dependency

http://wiki.ros.org/android/Tutorials/kinetic/Installation%20-%20Android%20Studio%20Development%20Environment

Comment: I mean my app module depends on libaray B, and libaray B depends on library C. Now I want to modify a class in C. My approach is to create a new class with the same name in the app module and run debug normally, and The loaded class is overwritten, but the above exception is reported when running release